# how to get the value of console.log and display in my input text after clicking the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, button

Html

```
    <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
<button class="btn btn-primary" >SAVE</button>
```

Javascript

```
    var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  let str = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${window.btoa(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById("svg")))}`;
  console.log(str); // para sa base 64 ng image 

document.getElementById("input1").value==str;
```

how to get the value of console.log and display in my input text after clicking the button

Comment: You had used = sign two times. **document.getElementById("input1").value==str;** thats comparision. so please check the answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

You can do somthing like this.

```
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()" >SAVE</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
      var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
      let str = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${window.btoa(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById("svg")))}`;
      console.log(str); // para sa base 64 ng image 

      document.getElementById("input1").value=str;
}
</script>
```